# Extend Markdown Parser to render custom code blocks

Tags: html, css, parsing, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I am building a static blog, which uses [Marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked) to parse markdown. I want to be able to have code blocks with tabs.
I want to parse code that looks like this:

````
```JavaScript
var geolocation = require("nativescript-geolocation");
```
```TypeScript
import geolocation = require("nativescript-geolocation");
```
````

To something like this (from the angular2 docs), where the tab names would be `JavaScript` and `TypeScript`.

[image]

I am programming in JavaScript (nodeJs), so I could manually render this if required? What would a custom implementation of a code block tab look like?

I am not sure if there is a special name for these, as I can't really seem to find any examples or templates.

Answer (score 0):

I think answer is: 'Marked' does not support custom tags. I've spend few hours trying to find some way to extend it and finally switched to [showdown](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown).

It appears to be really easy to implement one ( her is expandable `section` tag [example](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-site/blob/8ab8b18e4572b0c2d08926da4587d7e61733f659/src/app/views/%2Bdocs/doc-viewer/doc-viewer.component.ts#L87) ).

Extension 'showdownjs/prettify-extension' implements code highlighting using Google Prettify.